# Alamofire json requests failed

Tags: ios, json, swift

So I have the following code

```
@IBOutlet var jokes_list: UITableView!
var CountCells = 0
var CellsData = [NSArray: NSArray]()

override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad();

    Alamofire.request("http://localhost:8080/jokes.php").responseJSON{ response in
        debugPrint(response.result.value)   // result of response serialization

        if let JSON = response.result.value as? [NSArray: NSArray] {
            self.CellsData = JSON
            self.CountCells = JSON.count
            self.jokes_list.reloadData()
        }else{
            debugPrint("failed")
        }
    }



    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

I get the `debugPrint(response.result.value)` output, but I also get a `failed` from the else statement.

A bit of the output from the `debugPrint(response.result.value)`

```
Optional(<__NSArrayI 0x7fc9c6056a00>(
{
    added = "2017-01-10 19:07:14";
    description = "Ora de religie \U00een scoala. Profesoara: \U2013 Si copii, amintiti-va permanent: cei care vor \U00eenvata pentru note de 9 si 10 vor nimeri \U00een
```

It's a very long output, so I don't think I can paste everything here, however the question is why can't I set the json as an array to `CellsData` in the code, so I can use it to show the list.

Comment: What kind of JSON can be represented as `[NSArray: NSArray]`?

Comment: I had it as a String, but I changed it for testing, sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`as? [NSArray: NSArray]` definitively isn't correct, there-for the cast fails and the else branch is executed. It means that you are expecting a dictionary where keys and values are of type `NSArray`, but you have an array or dictionaries, so it should read `as? [[String: Any]]` or similar, depending on the response you didn't provide fully.

Also `var CellsData = [NSArray: NSArray]()` must pe changed respectively. (btw: please familiarize yourself with cocoa touch / swift naming conventions)

Comment: I've changed it to var CellsData = [String: Any]() and if let JSON = response.result.value as? [String: Any] { I still get "failed"

Comment: I'm just learning, I'm struggling with this for about 2 days now

Comment: of course it fails: you are having an array of dictionaries, but you just type it as dictionary. The "extra" pair of brackets is vital.